# Parse graphql fieldset string

Tags: graphql-java, graphql-java-tools, graphql-java-generator

I am writing custom directive as below (usage)

`@same (field: "user { address { zip } }" )`

How do I parse above value? I used `Parser.parse("..")` but it throws exception as it expects string to start with `{`. Basically it treats it as a `QUERY`.

My end goal in java is to fetch value of this field.